# Kaminari pagination in Rails 4 with glyphicon for links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I'm using the Kaminari gem for pagination in Rails 4. I want to use the < and > glyphicons (chevron-right and chevron-left) on the side of the pages to go to previous and next page, and can't figure out how to do that. Here's what I have so far:

To make a glyphicon into a link, I can use this:

```
<%= link_to "some_link" do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" title="Next Page"></i>
<% end %>
```

Kaminari also comes with `<%= link_to_next_page @pages, 'Next Page' %>` but that displays text on the page, not an image

Is there a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple; Using the logic in the explanation Beengie gave, I just needed to include some raw HTML in the link using 'MY_HTML'.html_safe

```
<%= link_to_next_page @records, '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>'.html_safe %>
<%= link_to_previous_page @records, '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>'.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Customize the views/kaminari/_next_page.html.erb in Kaminari

Remove this part of the link_to

```
raw(t 'views.pagination.next')
```

and replace with

```
'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>'.html_safe
```

**Update**

Make sure you have run this so you see the views to modify.

```
rails generate kaminari:views
```

For Bootstrap...

```
rails generate kaminari:views bootstrap
```

Comment: Can't do it - I get this error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)`

Comment: `<%= link_to_next_page @pages do %>` - I'm pretty sure that because this is a helper method for Kaminari, I have to include a title.

Comment: It did not. I still can't include an image.

Comment: I have Kaminari and just tested it. Are you looking to load an image or the glyphicon? Can you put up your _next_page?

Comment: Sorry, I've been totally misreading your comments! Where do I find _next_page in my rails app? It's not in my views anywhere.

Comment: I added the generator code so it's clear how to access the views if you have not set it up. enjoy!

Comment: Hey, so I almost got this to work! I followed your instructions, and customized _next_page.html.erb and prev_page. This changed the look of the navigation bar: `<%= paginate @records %>` However, it didn't change the behavior of the methods `<%= link_to_next_page @pages, 'Next Page' %>` which is what I really want to do. I want to add a glyphicon instead of writing text for my 'Next Page' link.

Comment: Okay, I DID IT! And I couldn't have done it without you. Here's the dirt simple code: 

`<%= link_to_previous_page @records, '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>'.html_safe %>`

Comment: Good job. Glad you got it figured out.